# JavaFX TableView with Custom Cell Datepicker "OnEditCommit" is not invoked

Tags: datepicker, javafx, tableview, cell, java-8

**Hi everyone !!**

I'm working with JavaFX and the JDK 8.

I got a **TableView filled by a database with the use of a JavaFX POJO Class "Inputs"**. I've implemented TexField cells, ComboBoxes cells and Checkbox cells succesfully.

But I am not able to make it working with DatePicker Control: the event on the **"setOnEditComit" is never invoked...**

**Hre is my code:**

**Declarations for TableColumn:**

```
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Inputs,LocalDate> colDate = new TableColumn<Inputs,LocalDate>();
     [...]
    colDate.setCellValueFactory(
                        new PropertyValueFactory<Inputs,LocalDate>("localdate"));

        Callback<TableColumn<Inputs, LocalDate>, TableCell<Inputs, LocalDate>> dateCellFactory =
                    new Callback<TableColumn<Inputs, LocalDate>, TableCell<Inputs, LocalDate>>() {
                public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                    return new EditingDatePickerCell();
                }
            };

      [...]
    colDate.setOnEditCommit(
                    new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Inputs, LocalDate>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(CellEditEvent<Inputs, LocalDate> event) {

        System.out.println("EVENT!!!!");
                            ((Inputs) event.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                    event.getTablePosition().getRow())
                                    ).setDatePicker(event.getNewValue());
   }
   }
   );
```

**With these JavaFX POJO Objects declarations:**

```
    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> localdate; 
     [...]

     this.localdate =  new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(localdate); 
     [...]
    public LocalDate  getDatePicker() {
            return localdate.getValue();
        }
     [...]
    public void setDatePicker(LocalDate  value) {
            System.out.println("EVENT!!!!");
            localdate.setValue(value);
        }
     [...]
    public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> localdateProperty() {
            return localdate;
        }
```

**EditingDatePickerCell class:**

```
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.time.LocalDate;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.List;

 import javafx.application.Platform;
 import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
 import javafx.event.EventHandler;
 import javafx.geometry.Pos;
 import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
 import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
 import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
 import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
 import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
 import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

 import com.desktop.newapp.utils.Inputs;

    public class EditingDatePickerCell <Inputs, LocalDate> extends TableCell<Inputs, LocalDate> {

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createDatePicker();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(datePicker);
                datePicker.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            datePicker.setValue((java.time.LocalDate) getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }

        private DatePicker datePicker;

        public EditingDatePickerCell() {
            if (datePicker == null) {
                createDatePicker();
            }
            setGraphic(datePicker);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    datePicker.requestFocus();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {

            if (datePicker != null && item != null) {
                datePicker.setValue((java.time.LocalDate) getLocalDate());
                commitEdit(getLocalDate());
            }
                setGraphic(datePicker);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

            }
        }


        private void createDatePicker() {
            datePicker = new DatePicker();
            datePicker.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
            setGraphic(datePicker);  



            datePicker.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED,new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() { 
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent t) {

                        if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                            commitEdit(getLocalDate());
                        } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                            cancelEdit();
                        } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                            commitEdit(getLocalDate());;

                        }
                    }

            });

            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        }

        private LocalDate getLocalDate() {
       return  getItem();
         ///return datePicker.getValue() != null ? datePicker.getValue() : getItem();
        }  
    }
```

I've been Googling a lot and I didn't find any correct implementation of the Java8 DatePicker Editing capabilities in a JavaFX TableView. Any help would be **very appreciate** !!

Without Stackoverflow I'll never could done the quarter of the whole job so **long life to Stackoverflow** !!

**Regards.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the table in editing mode (for the current row) when the user interacts with the picker. That can be achieved with an onShowingHandler like this (example is also with a color picker):

```
this.colorPicker.setOnShowing(event -> {
    final TableView<T> tableView = getTableView();
    tableView.getSelectionModel().select(getTableRow().getIndex());
    tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), column);       
});
```

then watch the valueProperty of the picker like this:

```
this.colorPicker.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if(isEditing()) {
        commitEdit(newValue);
    }
});
```

For more explanation have a look at my blog post: [Custom editor components in JavaFX TableCells](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2014/10/27/custom-editor-components-in-javafx-tablecells/).

Full Class:

```
public class ColorTableCell<T> extends TableCell<T, Color> {    
    private final ColorPicker colorPicker;

    public ColorTableCell(TableColumn<T, Color> column) {
    this.colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
    this.colorPicker.editableProperty().bind(column.editableProperty());
    this.colorPicker.disableProperty().bind(column.editableProperty().not());
    this.colorPicker.setOnShowing(event -> {
        final TableView<T> tableView = getTableView();
        tableView.getSelectionModel().select(getTableRow().getIndex());
        tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), column);       
    });
    this.colorPicker.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(isEditing()) {
        commitEdit(newValue);
        }
    });     
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Color item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);  

    setText(null);  
    if(empty) {     
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {        
        this.colorPicker.setValue(item);
        this.setGraphic(this.colorPicker);
    } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues but i ended up solving it with this post. [JavaFX8 – Render a DatePicker Cell in a TableView](http://physalix.com/javafx8-render-a-datepicker-cell-in-a-tableview/).
 The outcome is illustrated in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Model object is a bit strange. The `setDatePicker` and `getDatePicker` methods should be called `setLocaldate` and `getLocaldate`, to be consistent with the `localdateProperty()` method and (possibly importantly) the parameter passed to the `PropertyValueFactory`.

I don't think that would cause the problem you observe, though, and I can't see what else is wrong.

[This example](https://gist.github.com/james-d/9776485) works for me.
Have a look and see if you can see what I did that's different...

Comment: Thank You for your advice. I'm not good to the new Java 8 syntax and I did'nt succeded to "convert" it to standard java syntax. I think this a solution if I modify the MonthDay by a LocalDate...  I'll vote up if I succeed implement your solution... But anyway thank you for your reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
here is a datapicker cell edit when pressing tab key and go to the next cell 

datePicker.setOnKeyPressed /EventHandler doesnot work with tab
datePicker.EventFilter get called twice

to work arround this you need to add a listner to tableview cell and get date text as string and cast it to localdate
```

addEventFilter to TableCell  deduction object is a sample

=>  addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler() {...}

```
    public class DatePickerCell extends TableCell<Deduction, LocalDate> {

    private DatePicker datePicker;
   private TableColumn column;
   // private TableCell cell;

    public DatePickerCell(TableColumn column) { //
        super();

        this.column = column;
        this.datePicker = new DatePicker(getDate());

    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                    super.startEdit();
                    createDatePicker();
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(datePicker);

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                    datePicker.requestFocus();
                            }
                    });
                    //Platform.runLater(datePicker::requestFocus);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

      //  SimpleDateFormat smp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

       /* if (null == this.datePicker) {
            System.out.println("datePicker is NULL");
        }*/ //TO be reviewed

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {

            if (isEditing()) {
                 if (datePicker != null) {
                        datePicker.setValue(getItem());
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(datePicker);

            } else {
                setText(getItem().toString());
                setGraphic(null);

            }
        }
    }


    private LocalDate getDate() {
            return getItem() == null ? LocalDate.now() : getItem();
        }

    private void createDatePicker() {
        this.datePicker = new DatePicker(getDate());
        datePicker.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);

        this.datePicker.editableProperty().bind(column.editableProperty());
        this.datePicker.disableProperty().bind(column.editableProperty().not());

        this.datePicker.setOnShowing(event -> {

            final TableView tableView = getTableView();
            tableView.getSelectionModel().select(getTableRow().getIndex());
            tableView.edit(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), column);       


        });

         datePicker.setOnAction((e) -> {
             commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());

                TableColumn nextColumn = getNextColumn(true);

            if (nextColumn != null) {
                    getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(),
                                    nextColumn);
            }

            });


        datePicker.focusedProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(
                                    ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0,
                                    Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                            if (!arg2) {


                                    commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());

                            }
                    }
            });



        datePicker.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
              //   System.out.println("setOnKeyPressed datapicker get value  ...." + t.getCode());
                   /* if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                            commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());
                            System.out.println("Enter datapicker get value " + datePicker.getValue());
                    } else */if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                            cancelEdit();
                    } else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
                            commitEdit(datePicker.getValue());
                       //     System.out.println("Tab datapicker get value " + datePicker.getValue());
                            TableColumn nextColumn = getNextColumn(!t.isShiftDown());
                         //   System.out.println("nextColumn datapicker get value " + nextColumn.getId());
                    if (nextColumn != null) {
                            getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(),
                                            nextColumn);
                    }

                    }
            }

        });


        addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {

                    commitEdit(LocalDate.parse(datePicker.getEditor().getText(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
                     TableColumn nextColumn = getNextColumn(true);
                    if (nextColumn != null) {
                            getTableView().edit(getTableRow().getIndex(),
                                            nextColumn);
                    }
                }

            }

        });




//     
//    //    setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

            setText(getItem().toString());
            setGraphic(null);
    }



    public DatePicker getDatePicker() {
        return datePicker;
    }


    public void setDatePicker(DatePicker datePicker) {
        this.datePicker = datePicker;
    }

                private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }

        private TableColumn<Deduction, ?> getNextColumn(boolean forward) {
            List<TableColumn<Deduction, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
            for (TableColumn<Deduction, ?> column : getTableView().getColumns()) {
                columns.addAll(getLeaves(column));
            }
            // There is no other column that supports editing.
            if (columns.size() < 2) {
                return null;
            }
            int currentIndex = columns.indexOf(getTableColumn());
            int nextIndex = currentIndex;
            if (forward) {
                nextIndex++;
                if (nextIndex > columns.size() - 1) {
                    nextIndex = 0;
                }
            } else {
                nextIndex--;
                if (nextIndex < 0) {
                    nextIndex = columns.size() - 1;
                }
            }
            return columns.get(nextIndex);
        }

        private List<TableColumn<Deduction, ?>> getLeaves(
                TableColumn<Deduction, ?> root) {
            List<TableColumn<Deduction, ?>> columns = new ArrayList<>();
            if (root.getColumns().isEmpty()) {
                // We only want the leaves that are editable.
                if (root.isEditable()) {
                    columns.add(root);
                }
                return columns;
            } else {
                for (TableColumn<Deduction, ?> column : root.getColumns()) {
                    columns.addAll(getLeaves(column));
                }
                return columns;
            }
        }

}
```

in your class with the tableview

```
  Callback cellFactoryDate
                = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
                    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                        return new DatePickerCell(p);//DatePickerTest(p)  //DatePickerTest2     //EditingCellDate
                    }
                };


 dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));
        //   dateColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactoryTest);//cellFactoryDate
        dateColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactoryDate);
        dateColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Deduction, LocalDate>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Deduction, LocalDate> t) {
                        ((Deduction) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setDate(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution acceptable for all custom controls; this example use a ColorPicker control:

So finnaly I deal it like that: on the events of the controls I get back the POJO objects in use by the "**((Inputs)getTableView().getItems().get(getTableRow().getIndex()**" and I update similary like is it done in the OnEditCommit method...

So for me it's look like this (update the color):

```
 ((Inputs) getTableView().getItems().get(
                    getTableRow().getIndex())
                    ).setColor(cp.getValue());
```

Here is example with ColorPickerCell
:

```
public class ColorPickerTableCell<Inputs> extends TableCell<Inputs, Color>{
private ColorPicker cp;

public ColorPickerTableCell(){        
    cp = new ColorPicker(); 
    cp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            commitEdit(cp.getValue());
            updateItem(cp.getValue(), isEmpty());
            ((Inputs) getTableView().getItems().get(
                    getTableRow().getIndex())
                    ).setColor(cp.getValue());
        }            
    });                
    setGraphic(cp);
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    setEditable(true);        
}     
@Override
protected void updateItem(Color item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    cp.setVisible(!empty);
    this.setItem(item);
    cp.setValue(item);
}
}
```

With this simple JavaFX's POJO:

```
    public ObjectProperty<Color> color = new SimpleObjectProperty<Color>();

    this.color = new SimpleObjectProperty(color);

    public ObjectProperty<Color> colorProperty() {
    return color;
 }

public void setColor(Color color2) {
    color.set(color2);
}
```

I do not know if it's a good way to achive that but it worked for me... Note that the JavaFX's POJO is only accessible within an "ActionEvent" request (combobox, datepicker, colorpicker, etc..)

Regards,

Comment: No need for manually calling updateItem and setting the value if you put the table in edit-mode just before committing the edit.

Comment: cells _must not_ change the data under the feet of the edit mechanism